# log every item in JSON array in newline

Tags: json, node.js, bash

I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

node -pe "JSON.parse('[\"one\",\"two\",\"three\"]')" | while read line; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

which just logs one line:

> [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]

say I have an env variable of JSON:

```
json_array=\''["one","two","three"]'\';

function getJSON {
   node -pe "JSON.parse($json_array).forEach(v => console.log(v))"
}

getJSON | while read line; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

the problem with the above, is it logs "undefined" at the end:

```
one
two
three
undefined
```

Comment: Please edit your Q to show a usable value for `$my_json_array`. Good luck.

Comment: just did that, thanks for your input

Comment: @AlexanderMills: What is the output without the loop for `getJSON`? Also can you use other JSON syntax aware parser like `jq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This just happens to work fine, just have to separate items in the array with a newline character:

```
json_array=\''["one","two","three"]'\';

function getJSON {
   node -pe "JSON.parse($json_array).join('\n')"
}

getJSON | while read line; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

if anyone knows a good way to declare json without weird escape characters, that would be nice.

Comment: You could always read from a JSON file and declare the array by its contents.

Answer (score 1):

The `undefined` that it logs has nothing to do with the array that you've specified. If you try the same code in a browser console, it'll also print `undefined` at the end, because that's the return value of the `forEach` function.

Comment: You could also try with the `some` function, which'll print `false` instead of `undefined`.